# MongoDB text search with sort by score is very slow

Tags: mongodb, performance, optimization, mongodb-query

Looking for some assistance with MondoDB.

I have a MongoDB collection with 7.3 million documents, running on a server with 24 cores and 64GB RAM. I have created a text index for a single field.

When I perform text searches using the code below (in MongoShell):

```
db.getCollection('mycoll').find({$text: {$search: 'my search query'}}).limit(10);
```

I get results almost instantly. The only problem is that these results are basically useless because they aren't sorted by score (and it's beyond me why this isn't the default behavior, but that's a different topic).

I modify the command to include the sorting by score, as follows:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({$text: {$search: 'my search query'}, {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}}}).sort({score: {$meta: 'textScore'}}).limit(10);
```

and the command works, but it now takes about 10 seconds.

For a single or occasional query, it's not a big deal, but when I need to perform 1,000 - 10,000 of such queries in a batch we are talking now several hours of wait time.

I have seen some recommendations about adding "project" and "aggregation" but I don't see any improvement. Maybe I am not doing it right, so I don't want to put additional code here.

Any MongoDB expert that can provide some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure 100%, but mainly because you are trying to sort a full collection of returned docs, by field, which actually doesn't cover by index (it's more like a virtual field to be sure). Also, it seems that there are a lot of matches during the search, which actually slows the query at the sorting stage. Limiting results in your query, don't play much, mainly because it simple slicing of result after sorting. And in the first example, you just stop searching after first 10 results (no matter for relevance and textScore.

Comment: @Ruben Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: No I didn't - so I decided to move to PostgreSQL that has a lot of search functionality available

Comment: I don't think there is a "solution" for this using the built-in text searching functionality. As was already mentioned, sorting on the (dynamically calculated) score introduces a blocking operation that requires the entire data set to be processed (computing the scores and then sorting on it) prior to the initial batch of results being retrieved. If the MongoDB cluster is on Atlas then you'll probably achieve better (more flexible and performant) results using the Atlas Search feature.